# Problem with cyrillic characters in friendly url

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, friendly-url

Here's the thing. I have friendly urls like

> http://site.com/blog/read/мъдростта-на-вековете
>
> http://site.com/blog/read/green-apple

The last segment is actually the friendly title of the blog article. The problem is when I try to pass that segment to the database, the cyrillic fonts turn into something like **%D1%8A%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8** and couldn't match the database record. In the address bar in my browser it looks normal (**мъдростта-на-вековете**) but if I choose 'copy url location' the last segment again turns into these strange characters. I'm using **CodeIgniter** and everything is set to UTF-8.

Please help! :(

Comment: non-english characters aren't allowed in the url, thus, there is no way.

Comment: actually they are allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text is just being encoded to fit the specification for URLs.

Echo out the data to a log to see what you are actually trying to pass to the database.

You should be able to decode it with [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode).

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are ok, but if you want to use routing with cyrillic it isn't enough. For example if you have http://site.com/блог/статия/мъдростта-на-вековете you will have to do something like this:

In `config/routes.php`: `$route['блог/статия/(:any)'] = "blog/article/$1";`

In `system/core/URI.php` , in the `function _explode_segments()`, you can change

```
$val = trim($this->_filter_uri($val));
```

to

```
$val = urldecode(trim($this->_filter_uri($val)));
```

This will solve the above problem plus controllers and functions.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, **Firefox is cheating you here**: the URL actually is url-encoded, but is shown as if it wasn't. So copy-pasting and retrieving it on the server will have the URL encoded.

*(Not sure if other browsers behave in the same way.)*