# seo frienldy url is using cyrillic х character and it is always getting 404. How to fix it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode, seo, friendly-url

I have Seo friendly URL problem in my codeigniter web.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/change_route/$1';
```

here is routes.php in a config folder. Any request must to call change_route method of the main class.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class main extends CI_Controller {
    public function change_route($url='')
    {
        die(urldecode($url));
    }
}
```

This is my controller which is showing just request URL.

So my problem is here.
[http://localhost/safety/black-shoes-ар-гутал](http://localhost/safety/black-shoes-%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB)

Above url is working correct and displaying that "black-shoes-ар-гутал"

But [http://localhost/safety/black-shoes-хар-гутал](http://localhost/safety/black-shoes-%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB) this url is getting always 404. If i will remove cyrillic 'х' character from this URL so it will work correctly.

How can i fix it ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is my .htaccess .

Comment: • Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172396/2412335

Answer (score 0):

In routes.php file, use change

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE
```

this to

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

and also in your config.php file change

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

the uri will always be url-decoded 
and if you want to remove controller name from your url use this

```
$route['^(method1 | method2 | method3)(/:any)?$'] = "controllerName/$0";
```

if your methods having underscore like

```
 "function method_name(){
    #yourcode
}"
```

than use this

```
$route['method-name'] ='controllerName/method_name';
```

if I hope all of my above example will help you